# Отменить переход по ссылке, но изменить ссылку

Tags: javascript, html

Предотвращаю переход по ссылке с помощью js return false при клике, но при этом ссылка в адресной строке не изменяется, мне нужно чтобы она изменялась. Пример в react js использование роутингов, когда ссылка меняется, но переход происходит без перезагрузки страницы. С помощью аякса сделал переход, но надо еще чтобы ссылка изменялась.С помощью якорей не красиво, нужно чтобы было site.ru/about.

Comment: `window.history.pushState({}, '', '/about')`

Comment: [HistoryAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: @Yugofx, благодарю за решение!

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, благодарю!